# How can I track the execution of `source filename` command in mysql

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

How can I track the execution of `source filename` command in mysql so that I can have the filename and path of sql scripts that's been run. Google didn't help or may be I didn't use the right keyword.

So when I execute `source ./test/file.sql` (without errors preferably)
I want an entry in "source_history" table with current_time,filename(along with path) which I can do if I could figure how to track.

It'd be of great help if anyone could help me in keeping track of the command `source`.(Something like a trigger event for insert or update on table)

(may be, tracking all command in that sense and then while exiting mysql, get the query history and check for `source`)

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `source` command is not a MySQL command, it is a [command in MySQL's command line interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html), which is also named MySQL.

CLI only passes the sql commands within the file to the MySQL server, therefore the server cannot be aware of the exact file used for executing the command.

MySQL own documentation the `source` command (see the link above) suggests the most obvious solution:

> Sometimes you may want your script to display progress information to
>   the user. For this you can insert statements like this:
>
> `SELECT '<info_to_display>' AS ' ';`

So, the simples way is to create a table with fields for path, event type (start / stop) and a timestamp and add `insert` statements to the start and end of each sql file that log the start and the end of each batch and supply the name of the file hard coded in the insert statements. You may want to create a script that adds these commands to the sql files.

Alternative is to create a batch file that receives a path to an .sql file in a parameter, invokes MySQL's CLI, logs the start of the batch process in mysql, launches the .sql file, and then logs the completion of the batch in MySQL.

Comment: Actually thought of appending a line to all .sql file through script or an alias to run sql scripts before posting the question here. Expected a better feasible solution. Though this isn't convincing as the best, it's a useful one. Thanks a ton for your answer!